# Hazelcast jet data loading

Tags: java, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to load database data into hazelcast jet map instance

```
public void sourceStage(JetInstance jet, Pipeline pipeLine){
SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/development");
    dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql1 = "SELECT  id1 , id2 FROM public.tbl_data where name='india'";
    jdbcTemplate.query(sql1, new RowMapper<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            jet.getMap("t1").put(rs.getString("id1"), rs.getString("id2"));
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

and again trying to use same map as source in the pipe line

```
        pipeLine.readFrom(Sources.map("t1")).map(map -> {
            System.err.println(map.getKey() + "---" + map.getValue());
            return map;
        }).writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

and I see I'm not able to read the data as source.
but if check `jet.getMap("t1").size()`
I'm getting the size value.

Answer (score 0):

To load database data please use a pipeline with the [JDBC source](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/pipelines/sources-sinks.html#jdbc) and [IMap Sink](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/pipelines/sources-sinks.html#map-sink). Mixing both to a single stage breaks the parallel execution model of the Jet engine.